# Send ack to server from client after receiving socket.io payload

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

The server that I am communicating with needs an acknowledgement after providing its first response to continue providing responses. I am trying to figure out how to send an ack from my client. According to the documentation:

> The data is pushed by the server every 100 milliseconds, but the data
>   will only be sent to the client, if the client acknowledges the
>   previous data. In other words, to continue receiving the data, the
>   client must send acknowledgement. The acknowledgement code is 1
>   (Integer). var CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT = 1;

Here's what my code looks like:

```
@objc func attemptSubsciption() { 
   if manager.status == .connected {
      socket.emit("sub", ["state": true]) //This functions correctly
   } else {
      print(manager.status, "... will attempt subscription in 1 second")
      self.perform(#selector(attemptSubsciption), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
   }
}


func addSocketHandlers() {
   socket.on("data", callback: { data, ack in
      //Do required work. This functions correctly, but there's only one response                
      print(ack.expected) //This logs true
      //What to do here? How do I tell the server I've got the packet? I've tried something like ack.with([1]) or ack.with(["CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT" : 1])
   })
}
```

Most of what I've read online seems to suggest adding a callback function with my emit call, but that does not compile because the emit function does not accept a third parameter. I feel like I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try to pass the acknowledgement code directly inside the `ack`, doing so:

```
func addSocketHandlers() {
    socket.on("data", callback: { data, ack in
       ack.with(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good lord, that was really obvious! Thanks @Andrea!

Comment: Worked. Thank you.